# permissions access error

Tags: permissions, 404-error

I'm getting this when saving a post after editing:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/post.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

All file permissions are 644 and directory permission are 755 and owner is myftpuser:myftpuser (this is my FTP user login). I've tried changing all permission to 755 but didn't work.

Has anyone had this issue, is there a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes hosting providers will implement mod_security (and not mention anything).  Or else, mod_security was already on but a recent installation of a plugin or theme may have exposed this new problem for you.

You can try these four things...

1. Add the following to your .htaccess file (add to .htaccess, don't replace the other stuff already in it)

   ```
   <IfModule mod_security.c>
       SecFilterEngine Off
       SecFilterScanPOST Off
   </IfModule>
   ```
2. chmod **all** your folders (including plugin and theme folders) to 777 **temporarily** just to confirm that it's really not a permissions issue with file owner permissions.  If it is, then you can go from there (maybe your site isn't really running as 'myftpuser'.
3. Deactivate your plugins, one by one, testing your post after deactivating each one.  (See if a plugin is causing this).
4. Does the content you're testing have the word "from" in it?  If so, can you post without using that word as a test?

Comment: I tried 1. to 4. still no success. When I changed all to 777 I got a different server error, so changed back to 755 / 644 and the same as before. I tried putting the .htaccess file in the root dir, no success, and in the wp-admin dir, nothing. I will start from a new wp installation.

Comment: In the end I went for a clean install which worked. I appreciate your answer and believe it will be useful to other WordPress soldiers.